# Accessing Python/Kivy dynamic screen class

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So I've been working on an application that uses multiple screens, one of which is a settings screen with a theme chooser. The code looks something like this:

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
     
    def changeTheme(self, state):
        if state:
            # set the bgs of screens to black
        else:
            # set the bgs of screens to white

class Test(App):
    
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition: FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen())
        sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen())
        return sm

Test().run()
```

Kivy:

```
<MainScreen>:
    id: Main
    name: 'Main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: vertical
        Label:
            text: 'Settings below!'
        Button:
            id: 
            text: 'Settings'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Settings'

<SettingsScreen>:
    id: Settings
    name: 'Settings'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Dark mode?'
        CheckBox:
            id: darkTheme
            on_active: root.changeTheme(self.state)
```

The problem I'm facing with right now is that I can't figure out how to get access to `<MainScreen>` and `<SettingsScreen>` classes in order to change the background color. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you should first assing them to variables - `main_screen = MainScreen()`, `settings_screen = SettingsScreen()` - and later use it in `sm.add_widget(main_screen)` and `sm.add_widget(settings_screen)` and then you can access windows using variables `settings_screen` and `main_screen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must access `Screens` by using `id`, then you must specify the `Screens` as children of the `ScreenManager` in your `kv`, like this:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
        id: Main
    SettingsScreen:
        id: Settings
    
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'Main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Settings below!'
        Button:
            id: butt
            text: 'Settings'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Settings'

<SettingsScreen>:
    name: 'Settings'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Dark mode?'
        CheckBox:
            id: darkTheme
            on_active: root.changeTheme(self.state)
```

If your `kv` file is named `test.kv`, then you can eliminate the `build()` method entirely. Then you can access the `Screens` using the `ids` of the `root` (which is the `ScreenManager`) of your `App`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Though because I'm quite new to working with Python classes, as well as Python overall, can you explain the part "using the `ids` of the `root` (which is the `ScreenManager`) of your `App`" in greater details? Much appreciated!

Comment: For example, in a method your `App` class. you can access the `MainScreen` as `self.root.ids.Main`. In a method of the `MainScreen`, you can access the `SettingsScreen` as `self.manager.ids.Settings`. In other places you can refer to `MainScreen` as `App.get_running_app().root.ids.Main`, Of course, you can also use the `get_screen()` method of the `ScreenManager`.